# Postgres Trigger post write from spark

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create to Trigger on postgres after a table is overwritten by external spark program. Basically spark overwrites a table on Postgres and then the trigger uses that table to upsert records on another table along with some modifications. Will Trigger work in this scenario. If yes do I use update or insert trigger?

Edit:
Spark and SQL of the process.

Writing table from Pyspark:

```
df.write.format("jdbc")
        .option("truncate","true")
        .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
        .option("url", postgres_host)
        .option("user", postgres_user)
        .option("password", postgres_password)
        .option("dbtable", table_name)
        .mode("overwrite")
        .save()
```

Example trigger and function:

```
CREATE
    OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_trigger() 
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS $func$ BEGIN IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
    FROM
        information_schema.tables
    WHERE
        table_schema = 'public'
        AND table_name = 'test_table'
) THEN EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table as
            SELECT *,ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(col), 4326) as geom 
            FROM  spark_table';
END IF;
RETURN NULL;
END;

$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER insert_or_update_parcel_1
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON spark_table
  FOR EACH STATEMENT
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_table_trigger();
```

I have tested and the trigger works but it is only taking one row from the overwritten table and not all the rows.

Comment: Yes, that can work but it depends on all the details you didn't mention.

Comment: What would be those details?

Comment: Share the SQL involved in the different processes

Comment: Have provided details in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used [`FOR EACH STATEMENT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html), which means the trigger will fire once after the entire statement is executed, not once per row.  You may need to modify your function to either loop through the newly inserted rows in `spark_table` or perform a batch upsert (update+insert) into `test_table`. That last option (batch upsert) would look like:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_table_trigger()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO test_table
  SELECT *, ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(col), 4326) as geom
  FROM spark_table
  ON CONFLICT (your_primary_key_here)
  DO UPDATE SET col = EXCLUDED.col, geom = EXCLUDED.geom;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Since Spark is overwriting the table (essentially a series of delete and insert operations), an `AFTER INSERT` trigger is indeed relevant. (as described in "[PostgreSQL Create Trigger After INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE](https://linuxhint.com/postgresql-create-trigger-after-insert-update-delete/)" by [Aqsa Yasin](https://linuxhint.com/author/aqsayasin1/))

The trigger would remain:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER insert_or_update_parcel_1
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON spark_table
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_table_trigger();
```

I just made sure to use the same function name `create_table_trigger`, not `test_trigger()`.

---

> I need it to trigger once and then execute the statement which is taking the whole table and creating a new table if it does not exist.
> The spark code essentially truncates the table and adds new rows.
> The insert/update you provided would be the else part of the condition. The issue I am facing is that the trigger is working but in test_table there is only one row and not all the rows from spark_table. what I need is that the statement is execute after the last row has been inserted/updated
>
> When I updated/inserted on the spark_table from pgadmin, the trigger was able to take all the rows, but with spark only one row was there in the test_table.

So the issue is related to how Spark interacts with the PostgreSQL trigger. When Spark overwrites the table using the `.mode("overwrite")`, it performs a `TRUNCATE` and then a batch `INSERT`. Your trigger is set to run `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE`, which should ideally execute after all rows have been inserted. However, it seems to be behaving differently when the operation originates from Spark.

You could add an `AFTER TRUNCATE` trigger in addition to the existing one, to ensure the trigger fires after the table truncation operation.

And Instead of using [`.mode("overwrite")` in Spark](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-write-modes-explained/), you could try manually truncating the PostgreSQL table using a separate SQL command and then use Spark to `INSERT` with `.mode("append")`. That would ensure that the `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger behaves as expected.

Consider also adding debugging statements in your trigger function to capture what is happening during its execution. That could help you better understand why only one row is being processed when Spark is the data source.

> It  seems like a spark jdbc write issue. All `options(append, overwrite)` seem to execute the trigger after insertion of just one row.

If Spark's JDBC write appears to be causing the issue by executing the trigger after the insertion of just one row, you could explore alternative approaches to circumvent this behavior:

- Instead of using the `.mode("overwrite")`, you could manage the transaction manually and insert records in batches, followed by a commit.
- Or: perform the truncation and insertion operations manually using SQL queries from within your Spark application, ensuring that they occur within a single transaction. That would enable PostgreSQL's trigger to execute correctly.
- Or: write the Spark DataFrame to a temporary or staging table in PostgreSQL first. Then use a PostgreSQL stored procedure to move the data from the staging table to the final table, which can also execute the trigger logic.
- Or: use an external job scheduler or a PostgreSQL background worker that checks for table modifications and executes the required logic asynchronously. You could set flags or timestamps to indicate when a table has been updated and needs processing.
- Finally: after the data write operation, explicitly call the PostgreSQL function that contains the trigger logic from your Spark application using a SQL query. That ensures that the logic is executed immediately after the data write.

These alternative methods should provide you with more control over when the trigger or function executes.

---

> I'd be really interested if you could elaborate the last option ("Calling the function from spark application").
> I'd like to do it in a async fashion so that the spark cluster does not keep running while the Postgres function takes hours to complete.
> I have used psycopg2 which keeps the connection until the function execution is complete.

Invoking a PostgreSQL function asynchronously from a Spark application can be accomplished by offloading the function execution to a separate thread or process, which frees up the main application to continue its work.

You can create a PostgreSQL function to run asynchronously using the [`pg_background` extension](https://github.com/vibhorkum/pg_background) or by queuing the work to be processed later by a background worker. Unfortunately, native PostgreSQL does not offer built-in asynchronous function execution.

If you are using the [`psycopg2` library](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/) in a Python-based Spark application, you can execute the function in a separate thread using the `concurrent.futures` library (as seen in "[Debugging pool usage](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/advanced/pool.html#debugging-pool-usage)"). that would, however, still keep a connection open with the PostgreSQL database.

Here is a Python example using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`:

```py
import psycopg2
import concurrent.futures

def call_pg_function():
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database="your_db", user="your_user", password="your_password", host="your_host", port="your_port")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.callproc('your_function_name', [param1, param2])  # Replace with your function and parameters
    cur.close()
    conn.close()

# Asynchronous call
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    future = executor.submit(call_pg_function)
```

But:

If the PostgreSQL function takes a long time to run and you want to decouple your Spark application from the database operations, consider using an asynchronous task queue [like Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/).

1. The Spark application would write to the PostgreSQL table and then enqueue a task to run the function.
2. A separate Celery worker would pick up the task and execute the function, which frees the Spark application to continue other work.

That is a more complex approach, which would involve a message broker like [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) or [Redis](https://redis.io/) (for instance, `pip install celery redis`). Then you could set up a simple Celery task to execute the PostgreSQL function.

Create a new Python [file `celery_config.py`](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html) to store your Celery settings.

```py
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
```

Create a new Python file, `tasks.py`, and set up your Celery instance and task.

```py
from celery import Celery
import psycopg2

# Initialize Celery
app = Celery('tasks')
app.config_from_object('celery_config')

@app.task
def execute_pg_function():
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
        database="your_db",
        user="your_user",
        password="your_password",
        host="your_host",
        port="your_port"
    )
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.callproc('your_function_name', [param1, param2])  # Replace with your function and parameters
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

Start a Celery worker to execute tasks.

```bash
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

In your Spark application, you can now enqueue the task to be run asynchronously.

```py
from tasks import execute_pg_function

# Trigger the PostgreSQL function via Celery
execute_pg_function.apply_async()
```

Your Spark application will not wait for the PostgreSQL function to complete. The task will be picked up by a Celery worker and executed independently, achieving the asynchronous behavior you desire.

> If I'm not mistaken the celery process will run until the function finishes?

Yes, the Celery worker will pick up the task and run it to completion, but this will be done asynchronously, separate from your main Spark application. The Celery worker process will handle executing the PostgreSQL function and will remain active until the function execution is complete. However, this will not block your Spark application, which is the key advantage of using Celery for this purpose.

Once you enqueue the task using `apply_async()`, the task gets sent to the message broker and then to a Celery worker. Your Spark application does not wait for the task to complete; it continues its own execution independently. That allows your Spark application to perform other tasks or even terminate while the Celery worker continues to execute the PostgreSQL function.

Comment: I need it to trigger once and then execute the statement which is taking the whole table and creating a new table if it does not exist. The spark code essentially truncates the table and adds new rows. The insert/update you provided would be the else part of the condition. The issue I am facing is that the trigger is working but in test_table there is only one row and not all the rows from spark_table. what I need is that the statement is execute after the last row has been inserted/updated.

Comment: When I updated/inserted on the spark_table from pgadmin, the trigger was able to take all the rows, but with spark only one row was there in the test_table.

Comment: @Tarique OK. I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Yes, seems like a spark jdbc write issue. All options(append, overwrite) seem to execute the trigger after insertion of just one row.

Comment: @Tarique True. I have edited the answer with some possible alternative. Do you want me to expand on one of those alternatives in particular?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and providing alternatives. I think we would probably need to go through a manual or semi-manual route. But I'd be really interested if you could elaborate the last option. Calling the function from spark application. I'd like to do it in a async fashion so that the spark cluster does not keep running while the Postgres function takes hours to complete. I have used psycopg2 which keeps the connection until the function execution is complete.

Comment: @Tarique OK. I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll try these. If I'm not mistaken the celery process will run until the function finishes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255431/discussion-between-vonc-and-tarique).